# Counting integer in a nested list

Tags: python

Say I have a list `[1, [2, 1], 1, [3, [1, 3]], [4, [1], 5], [1], 1, [[1]]]`
And I want to count the number of 1's in the list. How do i do that with `.count` ?? Is there anyway to remove [] like `enumerate(seq)` which removes `()` then count the number of 1's in the list?

Comment: A) recursion B) flatten

Comment: C) use regex :) `len(re.findall(r'\b1\b', str(xs)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a function to traverse an arbitrarily nested list. Then the counting is trivial. The traversing can be accomplished with a recursive generator:

```
def traverse(val):
    if isinstance(val, list):
        for v in val:
            for x in traverse(v):
                yield x 
    else:
        yield val


>>> list(traverse([1, [2, 1], 1, [3, [1, 3]], [4, [1], 5], [1], 1, [[1]]]))
[1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 4, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1]
```

This definition would be even nicer with the new `yield from` syntax in python 3.3, with it we could replace one of the loops:

```
def traverse(val):
    if isinstance(val, list):
        for v in val:
            yield from traverse(v)
    else:
        yield val
```

Answer (score 4):

This might not be the coolest way, but it works:

```
l=[1, [2, 1], 1, [3, [1, 3]], [4, [1], 5], [1], 1, [[1]]]
>>> from compiler.ast import flatten
>>> flatten(l).count(1)
8
```

Here, as name suggests, `flatten()` converts the nested list into simple single level list. And counting the number of 1s from resulting list achieves the task.

Comment: It wont work in python 3 though as the compiler module has been removed.